# How to find the number of all available nodes to explore in Gurobi, instead of explored nodes?

Tags: python, gurobi

I am using Gurobi to solve a problem. My goal is to compare the number of explored nodes in different instances. But, for this purpose, the exact number of explored nodes is not important because in different sizes of instances it can be on different scales. In this regard, I want to find the ratio of the number of explored nodes to all nodes available for exploring.

I know that in Gurobi, I can get the number of explored nodes by:

```
model.NodeCount
```

But I don't know how to find all available nodes.

Answer (score 0):

The number of all possible nodes is not easy to define. Intuitively, this would be the number of all possible ways to define an LP by fixing the integer variables. In practice, though, every solver applies a number of techniques to never require to visit all those nodes (domain propagation, pruning, cutting, ...). Even the number of reported open nodes is not a good or reliable measure as it may not reflect the number you are looking for.

Maybe this paper is a good read to dive deeper into the topic of branch-and-bound tree sizes:

https://opus4.kobv.de/opus4-zib/frontdoor/index/index/docId/7814

Comment: Actually, the problem is an NP-complete problem. My goal is to distinguish easy instances from difficult ones based on the explored nodes. I am not sure it is a valid way or not but I am trying it by optimization in Gurobi. Let me read your recommended paper.